# Why the height of the weight balanced tree is logarithmic

Tags: binary-trees, trees

Could somebody explain to me why the height of a  weight balanced  binary tree in $O(\log n)$ in the worst case?

Comment: It isn't, if the tree limits the out-degree of nodes to 1. Otherwise, for example in the case of AVL trees, because the number of elements is exponential in the depth, which follows from the respective proofs of that property.

Comment: I explain it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13093274/550393

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

In particular, you're going to want to look at a proof by induction. Does a tree with 1 node have logarithmic height? Then look at a tree with $n$ nodes. When you add another node to a balanced binary tree, which you know to have logarithmic height, what is the worst thing that can happen to the height?

Answer (score 1):

Think of a Weight Balanced Tree (wbt) as a certain instance of a quick sort run. The invariant of the wbt indicates that the 2 halves of the sub-arrays to be sorted recursively are Theta of each other. This means that each tree of execution in quick sort will never be deeper than Theta(log n).